# Python Multidimensional List / Array

Tags: python

I am confused with Python arrays, I am used to using PHP and am trying to achieve what I think should be a multi-dimensional array but using Pythons lists.

I have the following HTML...

```
<section id="categories">
    <ul id="category_list">
        <li id="category84">
            <a href="www.example.com/samplelink">Sample Category</a>
        </li>
        <li id="category984">
            <a href="www.example.com/samplelink44">Another Category</a>
        </li>
        <li id="category22">
            <a href="www.example.com/samplelink">My Sample Category</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

And the following Python which creates an array from each list item...

```
categories = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#categories #category_list li a")

result = [{"link": category.get_attribute("href"), "text": category.text} 
          for category in categories]
print(result)
```

Is there such a thing as a multidimensional list in Python?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What are you trying to achieve? Yes, python has nested (or multidimensional) lists and they can be heterogenous: [[0, 1], [1, 2], [1, ['foo', [3]]]]

Answer (score 2):

That code actually creates a `list` of `dict`-ionaries, one for each link.

If you want to change the dictionaries to a `list` or a `tuple` (a list of constant size), you could change your code slightly:

```
list_of_lists = [ [category.get_attribute("href"), category.text]
                   for category in categories]
list_of_tuples = [ (category.get_attribute("href"), category.text)
                   for category in categories]
```

You would be indexing using [0] and [1] in both cases (instead of ['link'] and ['text']).